# unix find and cp first n files matching a pattern

Tags: unix, find, cp

I want to copy the first `n` (say 10) files matching a pattern from one directory to another. I am using MacOS X, so I don't have GNU `find` and `cp`. Here is my failed attempt

`$ find . -name "A*.xml" |head -10 |xargs cp {} /destdir`

It is the `cp` part that fails. I am able to successfully list the first 10 files starting with **A**

Answer (score -1):

figured it out. Here is how on a Mac

`find . -name "A*.xml" |head -10|xargs -J % cp % /destdir`

The **-J** uses the following '%' as a replacement string to replace the output from `head` into the `cp` command.